# Insert after TRUE in condition in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to insert my values if only they are not presented in my table.
I wrote the function:

```
    do
    $$
        declare
            v_video_config_bundle_id bigint;
            v_are_records_exist boolean;
        begin
            select id from config_bundle into v_video_config_bundle_id where code = 'video';
        
            select count(id) > 0 from config_bundle into v_are_records_exist
            where config_bundle_id = v_video_config_bundle_id
            and preference = 'true' and amount = 0 and repeatability in (1,7,14,21,30,45) and format='day';
    
            case
            when (v_are_records_exist = false) then
                insert into config_plan(config_bundle_id, amount, repeatability, format, payment_amount, preference_type, preference, trial, weight, status, is_default)
                values (v_video_config_bundle_id, 0, 7, 'day', 0, 'personal', true, false, 2, 'ACTIVE', false),
                       (v_video_config_bundle_id, 0, 14, 'day', 0, 'personal', true, false, 2, 'ACTIVE', false),
                       (v_video_config_bundle_id, 0, 21, 'day', 0, 'personal', true, false, 2, 'ACTIVE', false);
            end;
        end;
    $$
```

But I still get an exception ERROR:

```
syntax error at or near ";"
  Position: 1420
```

How to fix it?

Comment: This is what a primary key or unique index is for. For the columns that define the object's uniqueness, index them and then try your insert and catch the error that sarises if the column(s) values already exist

Comment: `CASE ... END CASE;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let SQL make all decisions; put all the determination logic into a single SQL statement. You can do this by converting the filtering logic into *NOT EXISTS (SELECT ...* structure. So something like:

```
insert into config_plan(config_bundle_id, amount, repeatability, format, payment_amount, preference_type, preference, trial, weight, status, is_default)
    with new_config ( amount, repeatability, format, payment_amount, preference_type, preference, trial, weight, status, is_default) as 
         ( values ( 0,  7, 'day', 0, 'personal', true, false, 2, 'ACTIVE', false),
                  ( 0, 14, 'day', 0, 'personal', true, false, 2, 'ACTIVE', false),
                  ( 0, 21, 'day', 0, 'personal', true, false, 2, 'ACTIVE', false)
         ) 
    select amount, repeatability, format, payment_amount, preference_type, preference, trial, weight, status, is_default 
      from new_config nc
    where not exists ( select null  
                         from config_plan cp 
                        where (cp.preference, cp.amount , cp.repeatability ,cp.format) = 
                              (nc.preference, nc.amount , nc.repeatability ,nc.format) 
                     ) ;
```

The above **is not tested** as you did not supply table description and sample data. However, see here for an [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=45974a8f86cb7b9ff8869a2dc272f2fe) of the technique.